# Hadoop single node installation error

Tags: java, hadoop, cassandra

I am trying to install hadoop-1.1.2 on Mac Lion with java 6.

I followed all the steps here http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/single_node_setup.html

but when the i do `start-all.sh` only `namemode` and `jobtracker` starts but not `datanode`, `secondarynode` and `tasktracker`.

here is the output:

```
hadoop-1.1.2 rachana$ bin/start-all.sh 
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

starting namenode, logging to /Users/rachana/software/hadoop-1.1.2/libexec/../logs/hadoop-rachana-namenode-scml-rachana.chegg.com.out
localhost: env: bash: No such file or directory
localhost: env: bash: No such file or directory
jobtracker running as process 5658. Stop it first.
localhost: env: bash: No such file or directory
```

I dont know what `localhost: env: bash: No such file or directory` means and what should i do?

Any help or directions are appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show me your log files?Pastebin or something?

Comment: Check the access on the files in 'conf' folder

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question

when I started each of the service independently using

$ bin/hadoop namenode 
$ bin/hadoop datanode

It worked.